# How to set sequence number for group in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that is grouped under a particular category. I need to show the sequence number for each group on the group header.i'm using iReport 0.4.1.

The output may be like

### seqno:1 group one

---

### seqno:2 group two

---

Answer (score 1):

Try with the variable `$V{REPORT_COUNT}`

from the [documentation](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-report-variables) :

> REPORT_COUNT which holds the number of records currently processed

See here for [related thread](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/500238/display-row-numbers)

Note : I didn't get how you were grouping records, but you should be able to do the appropriate operation on this variable to get what you want

Comment: It will give the total row count after each group. What i actually need is i need to show a variable which has a default value 1 and incremented by one based on group. Each group has several rows, i don't need the count for rows inside the group. Please help !

Comment: You should have a look at the link as duplicated